# Error in nonlocal keyword in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use `nonlocal` keyword in python in the following code. `inner()` is enclosed in `outer()` and I want to create a counter variable that will remember how many times `inner()` is called from `outer()`. `ctr` is defined in `outer()` and as `nonlocal` in `inner()`.

But I am getting error as `no binding for nonlocal 'ctr' found`.

```
def inner1():
    nonlocal ctr
    ctr=ctr+1
    print(' ctr= {0}'.format(ctr))


def outer1():
    ctr=0
    for i in range(5):
        inner1()

outer1()
```

Comment: `inner()` being called within `outer` is not equivalent to `inner` defined inside `outer`. nonlocal works with the latter.

Comment: *Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope*... Where is that variable defined in the enclosing scope??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inner() is enclosed in outer()

**No**, `inner` is not enclosed in `outer` (not defined within the scope of `outer`), you're only calling `inner` from `outer`; there isn't any closure here.